# Using SSL Certification in Multiple Locations

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

I have some issues with respect to using SSL Certificates. I have a website hosted in UK and I also have an organisation in South Africa hosting my company application online for web access.

The issue now comes as I want to implement SSL for both servers as it requires login from different places and different people.

Is it possible to purchase just ONE SSL certificate foe the company in the company name (www.companyname.com) and use it for both purposes? And hope there wont be any conflict issuing the CSR?

Thanks

Comment: You can get free SSL certrificates that work in all modern browsers from https://cert.startcom.org/ . They even allow you to specify an altName. companyname.com + whateverYouLike.companyname.com.

Comment: Cross posted at http://serverfault.com/questions/495771/using-an-ssl-certificate-in-multiple-locations

Answer (score 1):

When client browsers connect to a SSL server, they check that the *server name* (as specified in the URL) is part of the name(s) which are present in the certificate. Exact rules are given in all their technical glory in [RFC 2818, section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1).

For your situation, sharing the certificate between the two servers will work if they both share the same DNS name (but this may prove difficult, since they are likely to have distinct IP addresses), or if you convince your certificate issuer to give you a certificate with both server names in it (since the business model of most commercial CA relies on selling as many certificates as possible, they may object to selling you a single certificate instead of two).

One additional point is that *private keys* ought to travel as least as possible. If both servers share the same certificate, then they know the same private key, so the private key *must* have traveled quite a bit (at least from UK to South Africa, or the opposite). This can be done relatively safely (e.g. through some SSH connection) but, on a general basis, this is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You have one website which is hosting in two different locations, and you want to secure that website with SSL.

Now let see what the solution is,

SSL Certificate is issued with FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) not for IP address or server. So here is the question, which SSL will secure your domain name on both servers at minimal price.

Now there are some trusted certificate authority offer ssl having unlimited server license at free cost, and the others are charged extra for per server license.

Dedicated IP address is required for your domain name in both servers